# JMeter SHA256 in request header

Tags: jmeter, sha256

I am load testing an API using Jmeter. The Header of the request has an authentication request which needs me to Base64 the url+Nonce+Unix timestamp and SHA256 the resultant value with a secret key.
The above needs to be passed in header along with Nonce and timestamp.

For the above scenario should I create a custom function or use any preprocessor ?

Comment: I didn't ask for program, I am just asking what would be the best way to go!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it via [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as follows:

1. Add a HTTP Header Manager as a child of your HTTP Request sampler
2. Add aforementioned Beanshell PreProcessor the same way
3. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.DigestScheme; // necessary imports
   import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
   import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;

   String url = sampler.getUrl().toString(); // get URL
   String nonce = DigestScheme.createCnonce(); // get nonce
   long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

   String combined = url + nonce + timestamp; // put everything together

   byte[] base64 = Base64.encodeBase64(combined.getBytes()); // encode as Base64

   String headerValue = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(base64); // encode SHA256 

   sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("headerName", headerValue)); // add generated header to request
   ```

   - `sampler` here is a shorthand reference to parent HTTP Request Sampler class which I believe is [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) so its methods are used to get URL and add generated header value.
   - methods to generate MD5 hash and SHA256 hex are from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) libraries which are widely used under JMeter's hood.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: This is another option, I will try. Right now I am trying to create a custom Java class now and import it into the lib folder and use the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a BSF Pre-Processor in JavaScript mode to do everything the client normally would.  You'll have to take the client JS and modify it to work without FORM data.

You can build the entire header in JS exactly like a client would.  BSF Pre-Processor allows you to access jmeter run-time variables, so you would create a new one to store the SHA256 hash value, and use that in a HTTP Header Manager of the sample that needs the authorization.

-Addled

Comment: Thanks. Right now I am trying to create a custom Java class now and import it into the lib folder and use the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded eclipse. 
Wrote a custom jmeter package. 
Exported it as a .jar from eclipse to jmeter lib/ext folder.
Called the package function in beanshell sampler

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

@dmitrit's answer is helpful but I needed to do some tweaks to the code to get it to work. Here is what I did:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

String apiKey = vars.get("ApiKey");
String apiSecret = vars.get("ApiSecret");
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

String combined = apiKey + apiSecret + timestamp;

String generatedSignature = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(combined);

vars.put("GeneratedSignature", generatedSignature);
```

Note the main differences are:

- *Most important*: `DigestUtils.sha256Hex` takes a `String` instead of a byte array. Converting first to bytes screwed up the hash, I think due to padding.
- I added the resulting value to `vars` so it can be used later in Jmeter in the usual way (`${GeneratedSignature}`).
- `ApiKey` and `ApiSecret` are defined elsewhere in a Jmeter User Defined Variables element.

With this I was able to make the following work with Mashery in accordance with their authentication instructions posted [here](https://support.mashery.com/docs/read/mashery_api/20/Authentication).